# How to make verifications on specific instances of mocked classes with a given constructor in JMockit?

Tags: java, jmockit, java-11

I've been using JMockit to mock dependencies for a robot (such as sensors, joysticks, etc). For one of my classes' tests, I need to mock two joystick objects.

In the code I have, the Joysticks are instantiated as so:

```java
Joystick joystick1 = new Joystick(0);
Joystick joystick2 = new Joystick(1);
```

I've been reading up on how to match specific instances of objects in the [Instance matching section in the JMockit documentation](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#instanceMatching).

These steps however don't seem to work for verifications (or maybe I'm doing it wrong) or they involve using the `@Mocked` tag in the parameters of every test method which would be a hassle given the fact that I want this behaviour to carry for an entire class of several tests.

I cannot simply inject the mocked instances into the tested class since the tested class actually receives them from another class in the application, and I'd rather not mock my own codebase in order to pass in the injectable joysticks.

The behaviour that I'm aiming for is something like this:

```java
public class ClassUsingJoysticksTest {
    @Injectable
    private Joystick joystick1;

    @Injectable
    private Joystick joystick2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        new Expectations() {{
            new Joystick(0);
            result = joystick1;

            new Joystick(1);
            result = joystick2;
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        ClassThatUsesJoysticks classThatUsesJoysticks = new ClassThatUsesJoysticks();
        classThatUsesJoysticks.doSomething();

        new Verifications() {{
            joystick1.setRumble(1D);
            joystick2.setRumble(2D);
        }};
    }
}
```

Relevant portion of the class under test:

```java
public class ClassThatUsesJoysticks {
    public void doSomething() {
        Joystick joystick1 = OI.getInstance().getJoystick1(); // OI is our own class.
        Joystick joystick2 = OI.getInstance().getJoystick2();

        joystick1.setRumble(1);
        joystick2.setRumble(2);
    }
}

// OI class that we used to keep track of operator interface.
public class OI {
    private Joystick joystick1, joystick2;

    public OI() {
        joystick1 = new Joystick(0); // First joystick is always on port 0.
        joystick2 = new Joystick(1); // Next joystick is port 1.
    }

    public Joystick getJoystick1() {
        return joystick1;
    }

    public Joystick getJoystick2() {
        return joystick2;
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible using JMockit?

If you like, the actual implementation that I'm trying to achieve (with the bad mocking of my own codebase) can be found [here](https://github.com/FRC2706/2019-2706-Robot-Code/blob/b75ade14c1b73a4c06c253dba95446d567995146/src/test/java/ca/team2706/frc/robot/operatorfeedback/rumbler/RumblerTest.java).

Comment: Could you show your class under test? Your "it receives them from another class" smells like you should apply inversion of control and inject them there.

Comment: @chrylis added the class under test's relevant portion and the class that it gets the joystick objects from.

Comment: The second mechanism [shown in the documentation](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#futureInstancesByConstructor) should work... Did you try that? And there is no need to be "using the @Mocked tag in the parameters of every test method".

Comment: Don't use `OI.getInstance()` for precisely this reason. Make `OI` a constructor parameter of `ClassThatUsesJoysticks`.

Comment: @Rogério first time I tried that it didn't work but I just found out that it wasn't because the mocking wasn't being done properly but because it only worked on the first test that was run for some reason.

I got it working with a couple of setup in the `@Before` annotated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working with the current setup, as [documented](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#futureInstancesByConstructor).

```java
public class ClassUsingJoysticksTest {
    @Mocked Joystick joystick1;
    @Mocked Joystick joystick2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        new Expectations() {
            new Joystick(0);
            result = joystick1;

            new Joystick(1);
            result = joystick2;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testRumbles() {
        classThatUsesJoysticks.doSomething();

        new Verifications() {{
             joystick1.setRumble(1.0);
             joystick2.setRumble(1.0);
        }};
    }
}
```

If you would like to see the actual implementation, code is [here](https://github.com/FRC2706/2019-2706-Robot-Code/blob/ec09c9d7b67c939ec7feddd6ea33d90dfb3c04e8/src/test/java/ca/team2706/frc/robot/operatorfeedback/rumbler/RumblerTest.java).